# update Auth session

Tags: cakephp, authentication

How to update user information stored in `auth` session? without logout and login again.

I think this function will do it.. but is it the **best-practice**?

```
function update($field, $value){
    $this->Session->write($this->Auth->sessionKey . '.' . $field, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed `update` function to get an array of new values. with keys (field name):

```
public function update($fields, $values = null) {
    if (empty(parent::$_user) && !CakeSession::check(parent::$sessionKey)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!empty(parent::$_user)) {
        $user = parent::$_user;
    } else {
        $user = CakeSession::read(parent::$sessionKey);
    }
    if (is_array($fields)) {
        if (is_array($values)) {
            $data = array_combine($fields, $values);
        } else {
            $data = $fields;
        }
    } else {
        $data = array($fields => $values);
    }
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        if (isset($user[$field])) {
            $user[$field] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $this->login($user);
}
```

(thanks to [tigrang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377507/tigrang) for `login` function)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You could grab the current info array, modify it, and then call `$this->Auth->login($newUserData);`, but this will also renew the session (no user interaction needed, though). Note: Applies to CakePHP 2.0+ only.